# Set bias in CNN

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I have two massive numpy arrays of weights and biases for a CNN. I can set weights for each layer (using `set_weights`) but I don't see a way to set the bias for each layer. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You do this by using `layer.set_weights(weights)`. From the documentation:

> ```
> weights: a list of Numpy arrays. The number
>          of arrays and their shape must match
>          number of the dimensions of the weights
>          of the layer (i.e. it should match the
>          output of `get_weights`).
> ```

You don't just put the weights for the filter in there but for *each* parameter the layer has. The order in which you have to put in the weights depends on `layer.weights`. You may look at the code or print the names of the weights of the layer by doing something like

```
 print([p.name for p in layer.weights])
```